# Naruto: Tobi identity

Tags: anime, naruto

Who is Tobi in Akatsuki? I read the manga and it seems he said he is Uchiha Madara, after a short months of waiting the dead Uchiha Madara showed up in Impure World Ressurection. Now I'm getting confused if Tobi is really Obito as Rumored.

Question 1: Who is Tobi, please dont answer in Wiki. More personal beliefs would be more agreeable.

Question 2: When Obito died in the war where their sensei is the 4th, what time or what is the span of weeks, months, years did that happen before the Nine Tails attacked the Village? Because it seems Obito is a very weak Uchiha and if he is ever Tobi, what was the reason he attacked the village and how could he do that, he just awaken his eye, and he only has 1 Crushed Eye left.

Comment: this question is already nonsense.. since it has been answered in the manga. haha.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Question 1: Tobi is the mastermind of the opposing force of Naruto.  He would be the yang of the 5 great shinobi nations.  When Tobi first joined he acted childish and was underestimated by everyone.  Tobi has power but he doesn't show it until he wants too.  Bottom line is that Tobi's true background is still a mystery but we can see from what is there that he just wants to summon the ten tails.

Question 2: Its a rumor and not yet confirmed and I don't think the rumor is true because  Obito lost 1/2 his body.  Obito didn't hate Konoha and liked his friends from there, but Tobi apparently hates Konoha.  So Obito couldn't be Tobi.

Comment: Great point but I think ill wait for some more few answers. thanks for the interest in answering.

Comment: too bad. tobi is obito. sucks, i lost all bet haha

Answer (score 3):

If you are only following the anime, **spoilers** are below as they pull from the most current manga, which is much further along in the story than the anime. To get the latest scanlations, go to [Anifreak.com](http://naruto.anifreak.com).

In the manga, it's now *officially* revealed that **Tobi is [Uchiha Obito](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Obito_Uchiha)**, and the leader of the [Akatsuki](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Akatsuki). When half of Tobi's body was crushed by boulder, he did not die. It was Uchiha Madara that rescued him.

[image: Tobi's identity is revealed.]

Obito was able to awaken the [mangekyo sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan) when Kakashi killed Rin, someone they were both closest to.

About one year after his supposed death was the Nine Tails attack on Konoha. Obito was 13 when he was thought to have died. According to the Naruto [timeline](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/User:ShounenSuki/Timeline#1_BNT), the following year was when the Nine Tails attacked Konoha under Tobi's control.

He attacked the village because of his perception that Kakashi failed to protect Rin, which caused him despair and a loss of hope-- thus he adopted Madara's ideals of the [Eye of the Moon Plan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_the_Moon_Plan).

He obtained a new left eye sharingan after losing his original. And like Madara, he is able to control the nine tailed beast with his sharingan.